# Please could someone check my answer to this exercise about complex power?

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

I tried to solve the following exercise, please could someone check my answer and tell me if it is correct?

Exercise:  Calculate $\{a^b \} := \{ \exp(b \log |a| + i b \arg a) \exp (2 \pi i b k) \mid k \in \mathbb Z \}$

for $(a,b) \in \{(-1,i), (1, \sqrt{2}), (-2, \sqrt{2}) \}$ and also determine the principal value for each.

My answer:

$(-1,i)$: $$ (-1)^i = \{e^{-\pi -2 \pi k} \mid k \in \mathbb Z \}$$

principal value: $e^{-\pi}$ (the book defines the principal value to be in $(-\pi,\pi]$)

$(1, \sqrt{2})$:

$$ 1^\sqrt{2} = \{  e^{i\sqrt{2}\pi + i 2 \pi \sqrt{2} k} \mid k \in \mathbb Z \}$$

principal value: $e^{-i\sqrt{2}}$

$(-2, \sqrt{2})$:

$$ (-2)^\sqrt{2} = \{ e^{\sqrt{2} \log 2 + i \sqrt{2} \pi + 2 \pi i \sqrt{2} k } \mid k \in \mathbb Z\}$$

principal value: $e^{\sqrt{2}\log 2} e^{-i \sqrt{2}\pi}$